, which have helped to feed

Satellites track weather patterns and measure the effectiveness of
farming methods and innovations in agriculture, which have helped to
feed millions more than we could have dreamed possible before the
space age. (from Space 2.0 How Private Spaceflight, a Resurgent NASA,
and International Partners are Creating a New Space Age by Rod Pyle)


What is the antecedent of the bolded "which"? Considering "have helped" after "which", the antecedent is plural. Is it two VPs: "track weather patterns" and "measure the effectiveness of farming methods and innovations in agriculture"? Or, is it just "farming methods and innovations in agriculture"? Or, is it the previous clause as a whole?
If I change "could have dreamed" into "could dream", does it change the meaning of the sentence? What's the difference between using "could have dreamed" and "could dream" in terms of meaning, especially concerning referred time?


Regarding 1 - there isn't one! The sentence is complete garbage. You can't really learn anything from such a poorly constructed sentence with so many problems. The minimum fix I can think of is to change the comma to a dash and continue with assessments which ... But it's still an awful sentence.

I’m voting to close this question because the quoted text is just a terrible example of written English.

Q1
My initial reading was that the antecedent is "farming methods and innovations in agriculture". The antecedent should be a plural noun phrase, since verbs don't help feed people. And by default, the antecedent is usually the closest preceding noun phrase that makes sense.
However, because they compare this with "before the space age", they may have meant that using satellites to track these things has helped feed millions of people. If this was the intent, I think they worded it poorly.
Instead, I think they're simply conflating "the space age" with the age of modern farming technology. The innovations happened in parallel, and now we're using satellites both to improve farming (by improving weather tracking and forecasting) and to measure the effectiveness of all these technologies.
Q2
I don't think there's any significant difference between "could dream" and "could have dreamed" in this context. The qualifier "before the space age" sets it in the past, so the past tense verb is redundant. "could have dreamed" feels more idiomatic to me, though.

Thank you. Still, I am confused about #1. So, what do you think is the antecedent of "which" explicitly? As a side note, according to Huddleston, Grammarian, supplementary relative "which" can have an AdjP, VP, or clause as its antecedent. What I don't know about is whether the supplementary relative "which" can have a plural verb, because it usually takes a singular verb when it has an AdjP, VP, or clause as its antecedent.

I think it's what I said in the first paragraph, but it's possible I'm wrong.

I think the possible antecedents depend on the relative clause and what it makes sense for it to modify. In "I'm running as fast as I can, which is tiring me out", it makes sense that running is tiring. But I don't see how "have helped" can apply to the verb "track".

Both


Satellites track weather patterns, which has helped to feed millions more than we could have dreamed possible before the space age.


and


Satellites measure the effectiveness of farming methods and innovations in agriculture, which have helped to feed millions more
than we could have dreamed possible before the space age.


are grammatical.
The first sentence has the entire clause, '[The fact that] [s]atellites track weather patterns' as the antecedent of 'which', which is standard.
The second sentence has the coordinate noun phrase 'farming methods and innovations in agriculture' as antecedent for 'which', which is grammatically fine, but semantically/logically awkward ... one would expect say


Satellites measure the effectiveness of farming methods and innovations in agriculture, which have been shown to have helped to
feed millions more than we could have dreamed possible before the
space age.


But worse is


Satellites track weather patterns and measure the effectiveness of farming methods and innovations in agriculture, which have helped to
feed millions more than we could have dreamed possible before the
space age.


which can only realistically be parsed as twinning a main clause and a (coordinate) noun phrase as the antecedent, which is unacceptable lack of parallelism (arguably zeugma).
...............
One question only should be submitted in one post.
